# POE connectors on RaspberryPi

Tags: connection, poe

There seem to be jumpers to connect POE into the RaspberryPi. I have a case with two little fans which are meant to connect to the GPIO. I think they could be connected to the pins of the POE but I would like to know if this is likely to cause problems. I don't want to use POE.

Comment: If you want to "close" this Question, [please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If an answer isn't "selected", your Q will stay in the Zombie Box & come back to haunt us for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PoE "implementation" on RPi (3B+ & 4B) is a bit of a [sham](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sham) IMHO. I say this because [the necessary hardware is not included](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99902/rpi-4-poe-enabled-but-requires-hat).

As a practical matter, wrt powering your fans you would need to do a fair amount of work to use the power. POE is governed by a rather [complex group of standards and specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet). Delivery of power to the RPi's terminals would need to be *negotiated* with the upstream POE provider. Strictly as a personal viewpoint, requiring a "HAT" to use POE on a Raspberry Pi strikes me as some type of a joke - but personal viewpoints aside, in your case I'd opine there are better and easier (certainly less expensive) methods to power a fan.

If you want a more *practical* way to power your fan, this [question has been asked and answered here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56254/cooling-fan-powered-directly-from-gpio), and in a variety of blog posts - [for example](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/raspberry-pi-4-needs-fan-heres-why-and-how-you-can-add-one).

If this doesn't fully address your question, please let us know.

Comment: I wasn't clear. There are four jumpers associated with POE. I wondered if two of them had 5 Volts on them that I could tap onto to power my fans. My case is a bit of a tight fit and I can't put a meter on them.

Comment: @Mjp: I would **guess** No, but that would only be a guess. I'd suggest you [read this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/102324/83790), and make a comment to the author (Peter Green) - he seems to know something about this!

Comment: Oh well, bang goes that idea. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

POE voltage range is 37 to 57 V. Unless your fans support such high voltages, there's no point in connecting them there.

If you don't connect your Pi to a POE source, then there will be no substantial voltage on the POE header, and the fans will also not work.